# Putting the mysql statement in django python shell

Tags: mysql, django, shell

guys. I hope that someone of you can help me in that problem.

How can I express this MySQL statement:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column, (SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column2, 'aeskey') FROM table2)) FROM table WHERE id=1;
```

in django python shell (you know, with interactive shell)?

Thank you, have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django allows you to create your own [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/)

```
class AESDecrypt(Func):

    function = 'AES_DECRYPT'
```

If you do not override the `template` attribute then when this function is used it generates SQL like `AES_DECRYPT(arg1, arg2)`. This can then be used like so (I haven't tested this so may need some tweaking)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    id=1
).annotate(
    decrypted_aes_key=AESDecrypt('column2', key)
).annotate(
    decrypted_column=AESDecrypt('column', F('decrypted_aes_key'))
).values(
    'decrypted_column'
)
```